# Smoothing a function with jump discontinuity without blow up in Lipschitz constant

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convolution

Suppose that we consider the function $F: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$, defined by
$$ F(x)=  \begin{cases} 
      \widetilde{F} (x), & x \in K, \\
      0, & x \not\in K. 
   \end{cases}
$$

where $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and that $\widetilde{F}: K \to \mathbb{R}$ is in $C^{\infty}$. To mollify $F$, a common technique is to convolve with a sequence of mollifers $\{ \varphi_{\varepsilon} \}_{\varepsilon>0}$, such as those corresponding to the bump function.
$$F_{\varepsilon} := \varphi_{\varepsilon} \ast F$$ does the job.

> However, with most mollifiers, $\| F_{\varepsilon} \|_{\text{Lip}}$ goes to infinity as $\varepsilon \to 0^{+}$. Is there a method of smoothing that can prevent this from happening?

Comment: what kind of convergence do you want  for $F_\epsilon \rightarrow F$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+$? Depending on which type of function you are convolving with, you will have convergence pointwise a.e. and in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for $1\leq p<\infty$ or only in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Comment: @Xiao Pointwise convergence. This should hold as $F \in L^1_{\text{Loc}} (\mathbb{R}^d)$ by the way it is defined. Anyway, how does this matter for my problem about the Lipschitz constant?

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible to approximate pointwise a discontinuous function by a sequence of Lipschitz functions with uniformly bounded Lipschitz constant. You can prove easily that if $f_n \to f$ pointwise and the Lipschitz constants of $f_n$ are all bounded by $L$, then $f$ is Lipshitz with constant $L$. Just note that

$$|f_n(x) - f_n(y)| \leq L|x-y|$$

for all $x,y,n$, and send $n\to \infty$ to find that

$$|f(x) - f(y)|\leq L|x-y|.$$